# "USB Device is busy with previous request. Please Try again later"

Tags: wireless-networking, virtualbox, virtual-host, kali-linux, usb-network-adapter

USB wireless network adapter not working in Virtual Box kali machine. What to do?

It always gives a message that "USB Device is busy with previous request. Please Try again later"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with an USB Netgear WG111V2 connected to the USB 3 ports of an ASUS P8Z77-V LK. I solved the issue by connecting the Netgear WG111V2 to the internal USB 2 port.